package import function permission problem
I have wrote this code and it gives permission Error: [Errno 13] permission denied .
I am using python on visual code
NOT !! I have installed pillow package recently.
Windows 10
Hp pavilion
From PIL import Image 

myimage = Image.open(sky.JPEG)

Print(myimage) 

I tried to set on visual code as administrator.
Changing sky.JPEG place
Writing full path of sky.JPEG

first use ``` (or shortcut Ctrl+K) to format code.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

maybe first check if this file really exists - you may need to use /full/path/to/image.jpg because it may not find it. You may also check in what folder it runs code - see Current Working DIrectory - print( os.getcwd() ). You may also check what you have in this folder print( os.listdir() )
